# Google calendar login with web-bot

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am making a web-bot that checks every day if I have a new work in my time table.

If there is a new work date then it must add it to my Google Calendar.

But how do I login with the Google Calendar API, because the web page is not accessed by users. So how do I do that?

Comment: Look at this:) 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: @Andurit I looked at that but that doesnt answer how i do it for a web bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Google API docs for web bots. However I found a Github repo called [Telegram bot using Google Calendar API](https://github.com/demian85/google-calendar-telegram-bot). This bot can interact with Google Calendar API, allowing you to easily add/manage events.
According to their page, this is currently up and running and you may use it:

`https://telegram.me/google_calendar_bot`

Also, since you're not going to use manual authorization from users, [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) might be able to help you in the log-in part.